# Logging in to website programmatically Android

Tags: android, authentication, jsoup

I am creating an app which needs to login to a website programmatically. I tried to use this code, but it doesn't log me in.

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://omegastrike.co.uk/member.php?action=login")
                    .data("username", username, "password", password)
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .method(Method.POST)
                    .execute();
            
            Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();

            Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect("http://omegastrike.co.uk/index.php")
                    .cookies(cookies)
                    .get();
            

            System.out.println(doc2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Bonus question: How do I use this logged in connection for other functionalities in the app? Do I need to keep logging in?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't log me in"?  What output are you looking for as a sign of success?

Comment: The second connect html page result should contain certain text. Containing my username. But it still says: "Welcome, guest"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you look at the login form for this page, the raw HTML looks like this:

```
    <form method="post" action="member.php">
        <table border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="login_username">Username:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="" style="width: 95%;" maxlength="30" size="25" name="username" class="textbox" id="login_username" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="login_password">Password:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" value="" style="width: 95%;" size="25" name="password" class="textbox" id="login_password" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label class="smalltext" title="If ticked, your login details will be remembered on this computer, otherwise, you will be logged out as soon as you close your browser."><input type="checkbox" value="yes" checked="checked" name="remember" class="checkbox"> Remember Me</label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: right;">
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" id="button_postbit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" value="do_login" name="action" />
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="url" />
    </form>
```

As you can see, this is a `POST`, to the URL `http://omegastrike.co.uk/member.php`.  There are several fields being submitted, not just username and password.  The fields are:

```
    [username] => namehere 
    [password] => passhere 
    [remember] => yes 
    [submit] => Login 
    [action] => do_login
```

So you need to include all of those in your POST request.

It would look something like this:

```
    Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://omegastrike.co.uk/member.php")
                .data("username", username, "password", password, "submit", "Login", "action", "do_login")
                .followRedirects(true)
                .method(Method.POST)
                .execute();
```

As to staying logged in, I don't have an account with which to test, but generally there is a session id header or a cookie set upon login, that if included with subsequent requests, will keep you logged in.

Comment: Great it is working now! :) How do I find out how they remember it? Propably using the network tab in the inspect element function?

Comment: Look at the headers and cookies sent back in the response to the login.  Try sending those in a subsequent request one at a time until you see which one controls your session.

Comment: If you use Apache Components you don't need to bother about sending Cookies, in my experience, they will be sent automatically by the HttpClient object.

Comment: I have written essentially the same code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640844/login-to-website-through-jsoup-not-working) yet it is not working.. Would you please take a quick look?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
...

    Jsoup.connect("http://omegastrike.co.uk/member.php")
                        .data("username", username, "password", password, "submit", "Login", "action", "do_login")  

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Apache HTTP Components`. HttpPost will do the job for you. Make sure you spoof the `User-Agent`, because some servers are set to accept only certain browsers. Also using Wireshark as a sniffer is highly recommended.